# Prove that $(ab = -b )\land (a\ne 0)\implies a+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having some troubles proving the implication that if $ab=-b$, and $b$ is not equal to $0$, then $a=-1$. I am only supposed to use axioms of integers to prove the proposition. I have written a proof, though I am not sure if it achieves its purpose. I am looking for some help to improve my proof where it may be weak.

Let $a,b$ be elements of integers. If $ab = -b$, then $a+1 = 0$

$ab = -b \implies ab+b = -b+b \implies ab+b = 0$

If $ab+b = 0$, then $ab+b = 0 = a+1$.

$a+1 = 0 \implies b(a+1) = 0 \implies ba+b = 0 \implies ab+b = 0$.

$ab+b = a+1 \implies b(a+1) = a+1 $

Here is where I get stuck. I need to prove $ab+b = a+1 \implies b(a+1) = a+1 \implies b=1$ Is there a way I can do so without division? So far I have this: $\implies (a+b)|(ba+b)=(a+b)|(a+b) \implies b=1$ Though I would like to avoid division if possible?

If $b=1$, then $ab=-b \implies a(1)=-(1) \implies a=-1$

As proven, $ab = -b$, then $a+1=0$.

If you have another approach to proving the implication, I'd really appreciate it if you could share it with me. I'm looking for some alternate methods to prove it.

Comment: It’s not true if $b=0.$

Comment: First, the proposition you are trying to prove does not hold as stated. Second, you are correct up to “If $ab+b=0$, then $ab+b=0=a+1$.” You have no warrant for asserting $a+1=0$ at that stage, which is, after all, what you are trying to prove; if you could have asserted that, you’d be done and the extra two lines are a waste of time. They aren’t, because you **cannot** conclude $0=a+1$.

Comment: From $ab+b=0$, you *can* conclude by using the distributivity axiom, that $(a+1)b=0$. At that point, if these are integers, you may conclude that *either* $a+1=0$, *or* that $b=0$. But then you’re stuck.

Comment: By the way: please use MathJax for mathematics. [Here’s a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I forgot to add that b is not equal to 0. I don't completely understand how I can prove that a+1 =0. If I use distributivity to say that (a+1)b=0, then what do I do next?

Comment: You either *know* or must *prove* that if $xy=0$ with $x,y\in\Bbb Z$, then either $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: You cannot use the fact that $a+1=0$ to prove $a+1=0$

Comment: I appreciate the help so far, but can someone show me how to prove it correctly. I'm stuck and I've been at it for a while.

Comment: If you know that in the integers the only way a product can be equal to $0$ is if one factor is zero, then from $(a+1)b=0$ you can conclude, **as I already said**, that either $a+1=0$ or that $b=0$. If in addition you already know that $b\neq 0$, then you have absolutely everything you need, and what you are now asking is for us to write up a solution for you in full detail. Sorry, but you need to do *some* of the work.

Comment: @ElliotG: Nonsense: of course you can use the fact that $a+1=0$ to prove $a+1=0$; after all, $P\implies P$ is a tautology. If “$a+1=0$” is a fact, then you’re done. Rather, you should not **assume** that $a+1=0$ if you are trying to *prove* that $a+1=0$.

Comment: I made some changes, though I don't know if I have proven that $b(a+1)=(a+1) \implies b=1$ To prove that I would have to divide $(a+1)$ from both sides, and I am not sure how to prove that $(a+1)|(a+1) = 1$

Comment: What you have added is nonsensical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ ab = -b $$
$$ ab + b = 0$$

Using converse of distributive property,

$$ b (a+1) = 0 $$

Now for $b(a+1)$ to be zero either $b$ or $a+1$ has to be zero. Since it is given that b is not zero so $a+1$ will be zero

$$ a+1=0\implies a = -1 $$

Hence proved that $a+1$ is zero as well as $a = -1$